# accessing my local site from a remote computer

Tags: asp.net, http, iis-7.5, tcp

I have IIS 7.5 installed on my computer.
I have one site configured on it.
It has binding on port 80 with IP all unassigned.
I want to reach that site from a remote computer i.e. not inside the LAN.
I also configured port forwarding to my LAN IP but I still can't reach it.
Is there something else I need to do in order to achieve it?

telnet from computer to port 80 succeed but from a remote it doesn't succeed.

These are the configurations in my router:

10.0.0.2
External Port Start 
1

External Port End
65000

Internal Port Start
80
Internal Port End
80

Answer (score 0):

Ok - it was a problem with my router configurations:
I set port 80 for both external and internal and no I reached my computer